# How can I access a contract's fallback function via 'myContract.methods'?

Tags: web3js, fallback-function

Web3.js documentation says [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12) that the methods of a smart contract are available through:

1. The name: `myContract.methods.myMethod`
2. The name with parameters: `myContract.methods['myMethod(uint256)']`
3. The signature: `myContract.methods['0x58cf5f10']`

But how can I access the contract's fallback function, which has no name (and no parameters)?

Will the 2nd option work if I use `myContract.methods['()']`?

Is there a way to make the 1st option work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Fallback functions are executed if a contract is called and no other function matches the specified function identifier, or if no data is supplied

so you can use the following:

`send Transaction` to the contract with the `msg.value = 0` and it will automatically  invoke the fallback function.

OR

call the contract using `myContract.methods` and provide the wrong or random `function name` or `signature` and it will execute the fallback function as it couldn't find the function with the same signature in the contract. (not tested)

**Update** (Tested on expanse network)

Tested the second option and it didn't work. As using `random` name in `myContract.methods` will return `undefined` because when `web3js` tries to find the `function` name in `abi` it returns `empty`. The reason being

[image]

other function in the `abi` have the name `attribute` and `fallback` doesn't have one
[image]

After that created a `raw transaction` with the `data` being empty and sent that transaction to the network which invoked the fallback function as expected.

[image]

And on `trace_transaction` it says `reverted` which the `fallback` function does in this particular case.
[image]

Comment: The first option does not answer my question ("how to use `myContract.methods`?"). In addition, the `msg.value = 0` is irrelevant, since I actually do want to send funds to the fallback function (which is `payable`). The second option - I sincerely doubt that it would work. I was going to ask if you've tried it, but it seems that you haven't ("not tested").

Comment: give me a minute, i'll hack something together to test the second option

Comment: ok, tested it using `myContract.methods["random"]` and it gives `undefined` as it couldn't find any function with the same name in `abi`. Then tried creating a `raw transaction`  with empty `data` value and it worked. In conclusion you cannot call `fallback` function using `myContract.methods`.

Comment: Thank you. I know that I can invoke a contract's callback function using the contract address in the `to` field, and an empty string in the `data` field. However, I have a general function which executes transactions, and this function relies on the user passing the transaction itself (not `to` and `data`). So I was hoping to understand how this function - **as is** - can support invoking the callback function.